# How come list index is out of range?

Tags: python

I am working on a homework problem in which you have to find a missing number in an arithmetic progression. While the first sequence has no problem and indeed returns the right answer, the second one gives me an error

"if sequence[i+1] != sequence[i] + difference:"

"IndexError: list index out of range"

```
def find_missing(sequence):
    diff1 = sequence[1] - sequence[0]
    diff2 = sequence[2] - sequence[1]
    diff3 = sequence[3] - sequence[2]
    if diff1 == diff2:
        difference = diff1
    if diff2 == diff3:
        difference = diff3
    if diff1 == diff3:
        difference = diff1
    for i in sequence:
        if sequence[i+1] != sequence[i] + difference:
            return sequence[i] + difference
    return difference

print(find_missing([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
print(find_missing([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Could anyone please explain to me how it is possible I am trying to access an element in a list which does not exist? 3 does not equal 1+difference(1), therefore it shoud just return 2. Please tell me what I am missing. Thank you.

Comment: for i in sequence: gives you the value each iteration, so sequence[i+1] would be 1+1, 2+1, ... eventually, you're trying to reference an index value that doesn't exist. Use for i in range(len(sequence))

Comment: This is a very common beginner problem; did you search before asking?

Comment: Is this the homework or to make a "find missing number" function?

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
for i in sequence:
```

i, in each iteration is the value in the list, not the index. If you want to iterate over indices, use something like,

```
for i in range(len(sequence)):
```

For your case however, you should iterate till len(sequence) - 1

```
for i in range(len(sequence) - 1):
```

In the future, if you get a list index out of range error, try printing the index at each iteration. Also, read up on for loops in Python

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in sequence:
        if sequence[i+1] != sequence[i] + difference:
```

You loop through `sequence` elements, not through their indexes. Thus `sequence[i+1]` where `i==8` is out of bounds.

Try looping with a `for i in range(len(sequence) - 1)` instead.